# USB error -110 (power exceeded) but works when reconnecting

Tags: arch-linux, usb

At the last boot, two USB devices were not powered:

- The Logitech G5 mouse works most of the time, but this time I had to plug it in (in the same motherboard USB port) three or four times before it would power up.
- The Wi-Fi USB dongle connected to the front panel which usually (not sure about always) does *not* get powered during boot.

It seems the issue [is](http://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) [power](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-797789.html) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110), which is a bit of a mystery: All the USB devices work fine on Windows every time, my PSU is pretty beefy, and more importantly, I'd been running Arch Linux with the same hardware for months before this problem occurred. People have suggested at least disabling USB autosuspension, some [`old_scheme_first`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=old_scheme_first) magic setting, [disabling `ehci_hcd`](http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/) and turning it off and on again, but with no explanation I'm reluctant to try "fixing by accident." Does anyone know a well explained solution or some way to debug this in more detail? `apropos -a usb log` returns nothing, and it seems quite difficult to know which one of my 7+ USB devices is to blame.

From `dmesg` of the last boot, in which both these devices were unpowered:

```
usb 4-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 4-5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 4-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 4-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 4-5: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
usb 4-5: device not accepting address 6, error -110
usb 4-5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
usb 4-5: device not accepting address 7, error -110
hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
usb 10-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
usb 10-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 10-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 10-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
usb 4-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
hub 4-3:1.0: USB hub found
hub 4-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 3-4: device not accepting address 5, error -71
usb 4-5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x11
usb 4-3.1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
rtl8192cu: MAC address: e8:4e:06:14:7a:77
rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
systemd-udevd[695]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlp0s29f7u5
rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-3/4-3.1/4-3.1:1.0/input/input14
usbcore: registered new interface driver xpad
rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
usb 9-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
input: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb9/9-2/9-2:1.0/0003:046D:C041.0001/input/input15
hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input0
hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input1
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s29f7u5: link is not ready
usb 6-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
usb 6-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
usb-storage 6-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi16 : usb-storage 6-2:1.0
wlp0s29f7u5: authenticate with cc:33:bb:13:8a:f4
wlp0s29f7u5: send auth to cc:33:bb:13:8a:f4 (try 1/3)
wlp0s29f7u5: authenticated
wlp0s29f7u5: associate with cc:33:bb:13:8a:f4 (try 1/3)
wlp0s29f7u5: RX AssocResp from cc:33:bb:13:8a:f4 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=56)
wlp0s29f7u5: associated
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s29f7u5: link becomes ready
```

Comment: If it helps, in my up-to-date Arch Linux it works fine

Comment: Was this subsequent to a kernel upgrade?  If so and you still have the old one available, check using that.

Comment: Did you use any of the USB auto-suspend features for power-saving? Not that this is something you can do accidentally, on Arch. I tried that, and my mouse wouldn't wake up until I clicked the button.

Comment: @ams Yes, I have enabled all entries in `powertop` called "Autosuspend for USB device [...] Host Controller". Let's see if disabling them fixes this...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I ended up buying a different Wi-Fi solution.